# where to put images for xamarin forms application

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am developing an application for Android, iOS and Visual Studio using Xamarin

I added the following lines in xaml to use images:

```
<Image Source="header.png" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
<Button x:Name="Object_Detection" Image="header.png" />
```

The first is for displaying an image in the header and the second is for displaying a button icon. They link for the same image "header.png"

I put the image under:
- Mobile.Droid\Resources\drawable
- Mobile.iOS\Resources
-Mobile.Windows\Assets

But the image is not shown at all in the Windows 8.1 app.
the image size is 690*79.

how to resolve the problem?

Comment: may have a look here:
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/images/
(Take care of build Action Option and platform ;))

Comment: They don't note where to put the image for windows 8.1 applications

Comment: Assuming no folders like your "header.png" example, place the images in the project/application's root directory with a `Build Action: Content`

Comment: Also note that on Windows the Image on Button behaves differently than on iOS and Android. On Windows it's still the normal button, but with an small icon in front of the text. On the other two it's similar to an ImageButton on Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your posts,

the solution was to add the image resource to the windows sub-project directly under the root.

The addition should be made using visual studio so that the image will be taken in consideration by the compiler.

Answer (score 4):

You have to place images in the root Project directory for Windows Phone 8, Windows Phone 8.1 and UWP applications.

This guide will help you
http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/images

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this :

```
  <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <OnPlatform x:Key="ImageHeaders" 
                        x:TypeArguments="ImageSource"
                        iOS="header.png"
                        Android="header.png"
                        WinPhone="Assets/header.png" />
       </ResourceDictionary>
  </ContentPage.Resources>

  <Image Source="{StaticResource ImageHeaders}" />
```

OR

```
  <Image.Source>
    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="ImageSource">
      <OnPlatform.iOS><FileImageSource File="header.png"/></OnPlatform.iOS>
      <OnPlatform.Android><FileImageSource File="header.png"/></OnPlatform.Android>
      <OnPlatform.WinPhone><FileImageSource File="Assets/header.png"/></OnPlatform.WinPhone>
    </OnPlatform>
  </Image.Source>
```

Not tested, but it seems to work well.