# Image is not visible in android project with XAML forms - Xamarin even though provided solutions applied

Tags: image, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I tried solutions from the following links but none worked.

[where-to-put-images-for-xamarin-froms-application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37378449/where-to-put-images-for-xamarin-froms-application)

[developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images/#Local_Images](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images/#Local_Images)

[image-not-showing-in-xamarin-forms-app.html](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/70757/image-not-showing-in-xamarin-forms-app.html)

I used below syntax

```
<Image Source="lock.png" HeightRequest="20" WidthRequest="20" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"></Image>
```

Here is the image for where i've kept image

[image: resource where Image is placed]

No image displays

[image]

**Edit**

[image]

[image]

These are the only things in my XAML page.

Comment: Did you check the build action for icon.png? It supposed to be 'AndroidResource'.

Comment: Can you describe it in details? i mean with steps. as i'm new to xamarin so don't have much idea.

Comment: Right click on the icon.png within the VS and check the build action. If you are not sure about this might be that you didn't follow https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images/#Local_Images

Comment: Have you checked if you put a layer above the Image? If you have childrens declared in your xaml, that are rendered after the image was rendered, they may overlap the image.Try setting BackgroundColor of elements declared later in the xaml code to green and see if they may overlap the image

Comment: Build Action is 'AndroidResource' @EvZ.

Comment: @Divya Can you share the full XAML? As Csharpest mentioned maybe there is another control on a top of your image.

Comment: @EvZ i've updated the code. you can see XAML page now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my case the issue was of `assembly`.
when trying all the possible solutions like

1.) Changing Build Action

2.) Adding Image to all the folders within **Resources**

[image]

3.) Naming Convention should not include `-` in File/Image Name.

4.) Changing Background Color

I also got one solution while searching for embedded Images that `assembly` was missing here.

[image: Image2]

This change worked for me in using Local Images.
Got that solution from this [link](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/36297/markupextension-not-found)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I need to use method `Forms.Init(Context activity, Bundle bundle)`, in my `SplashScreen` `OnCreate` method and `Activity` class `OnCreate` method. But it also important that images `build action` properties is set on `AndroidResource`.

Answer (score 0):

Right click the lock.png image and see if there is an option "include in project"

If there is, project cannot find image